# Interact with graph on web page

Tags: javascript, plot

I want to plot a graph (diagram) on html pages, and the graph could consist of multiple nodes (sub-graph). When a user clicks a node, I need to display some textual message somewhere on the page. Is this can be done by some JavaScript plot library? A google search found:

- Google Charts
- ChartJS
- DS.js

and more. Clearly, it can draw the photo for me, but my question is whether it can respond to user's action, i.e. a mouse click to display information for the graph. I have never used this and please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're a beginner, I'll advise you to use [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) or [Chartist.js](http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/), the other ones being quite more complex to handle with (especially [D3.js](https://d3js.org/)).

Your question is really really wide. If you want to be able to interact with user actions that happen within the graph, you should look at the *events* parts of their documentation and/or possible *callbacks*. A good example is in Chart.js when [a user is over an element](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-hover-configuration) :

> **onHover** Called when any of the events fire. Called in the context of the chart and passed an array of active elements (bars, points, etc)

You'll find many examples in their documentation and with a quick research through your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with d3.js. It is a good library to draw graphs.User interactions like mouse click also possible using d3.js